# How to escape "/" in a sed command in Puppet script?

Tags: puppet, sed, escaping

In a config file, I'm trying to replace `PREFIX=/jenkins` with, say, `PREFIX=/foobar`.

On the (bash) command line, this works fine:

```
sed -i.bak s/PREFIX=\\/jenkins/PREFIX=\\/foobar/g /etc/default/jenkins
```

However, in a Puppet script (.pp file):

```
exec { 'Change-prefix':
  command => "sed -i.bak s/PREFIX=\\/jenkins/PREFIX=\\/foobar/g /etc/default/jenkins",
  path    => ["/bin"],
}
```

produces:

```
err: /Stage[main]//Exec[Change-prefix]/returns: change from notrun to 0 failed:
sed -i.bak s/PREFIX=\/jenkins/PREFIX=\/foobar/g /etc/default/jenkins 
returned 1 instead of one of [0]
```

**How to escape the sed command properly?** Or is something else the matter?

I also tried with `\\\/`, but that yields: `warning: Unrecognised escape sequence '\/'`

Comment: It may be a better idea to let Puppet manage the whole `/etc/default/jenkins` file using a template, than to rely on an `exec` calling sed.

Comment: @daff: Yes, probably... But for my simple needs, for now, this suffices (and I'm not really familiar with Puppet templates yet). Later on I might change it to a more idiomatic Puppet approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In cases where your sed expression contains a '/', you may want to consider using a different delimiter. I chose the pipe symbol in this example.

`sed -i.bak 's|PREFIX=/jenkins|PREFIX=/foobar|g' /etc/default/jenkins`

Using this syntax in your Puppet manifest would be a lot cleaner and more readable, in my opinion.

---

From the sed info page:

> `\%REGEXP%'
>        (The`%' may be replaced by any other single character.)
>
> ```
>  This also matches the regular expression REGEXP, but allows one to
>  use a different delimiter than `/'.  This is particularly useful
>  if the REGEXP itself contains a lot of slashes, since it avoids
>  the tedious escaping of every `/'.  If REGEXP itself includes any
>  delimiter characters, each must be escaped by a backslash (`\').
> ```

Comment: This was new to me, but yes, it's a lot cleaner this way. Thanks (to both answerers)!

Answer (score 4):

On many versions of sed you can use a different character as a delimiter to avoid having to escape / e.g it's quite common to use | or #

```
sed -i.bak 's#PREFIX=/jenkins#PREFIX=/foobar#g' /etc/default/jenkins
```

Answer (score 3):

Whoa, whoa... hang-on! Sed in a puppet manifest is a bit crazy. You should be using the file_line resource, from the puppetlabs stdlib.

(you should install the entire module, but here is the custom resource type)
https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppetlabs-stdlib/blob/master/lib/puppet/type/file_line.rb

Example:

```
  file_line { 'sudo_rule':
    path => '/etc/sudoers',
    line => '%sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL',
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! `file_line` together with `match` attribute is exactly what did the job!

Answer (score 1):

Turns out **`\\\\/`** works.

For example:

```
exec { 'Change-prefix':
  command => "sed -i.bak s/PREFIX=\\\\/jenkins/PREFIX=\\\\/foorbar/g /etc/default/jenkins",
  path    => ["/bin"],           
}
```

**Edit**: ...but of course using a different delimiter, as [Kenny](https://serverfault.com/a/486628/1746) and [Iain](https://serverfault.com/a/486629/1746) suggested, is a lot cleaner solution!